# Storing matching pairs of numbers efficiently in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, where-clause

I am building an SQLite database which will serve to store information about pairs of genes (orthologs). Each gene ID (an integer) is associated with a taxon ID (also an integer). Each table row (as I have it now) contains four numbers: taxon1, gene1, taxon2, gene2, for example

```
taxon1  gene1   taxon2  gene2
7955    571872  7994    103025831
7955    571872  31033   101063396
9031    395159  7955    767804
9031    395159  8128    100690390
9031    395159  9103    100544288
```

Now, if I want to look up all genes which form a pair between two taxons, say 25 and 37, I need to run two queries, since I have no guarantee that 25 is in the first column:

```
SELECT taxon1, gene1, taxon2, gene2 FROM orthologs WHERE taxon1=25 AND taxon2=37
SELECT taxon2, gene2, taxon1, gene1 FROM orthologs WHERE taxon2=25 AND taxon1=37
```

Likewise, if I want to have all genes which match the gene 123 from taxon 55 I need to look up both gene1 and gene2.

I don't know much SQL, but this does not seem like an efficient solution; maybe I am missing something? Maybe there is a much better way of solving this? I could of course have two tables (one for mapping genes to taxons, and the second one for gene pairs), but I would still have to look up both columns of the second one at times.

My main concern is the size of the SQLite file, it should be as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions [`MIN()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc) and [`MAX()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc):

```
SELECT taxon1, gene1, taxon2, gene2 
FROM orthologs 
WHERE MIN(taxon1, taxon2) = 25 AND MAX(taxon1, taxon2) = 37
```

If the values of 25 and 37 come as parameters, you can do this:

```
SELECT taxon1, gene1, taxon2, gene2 
FROM orthologs 
WHERE MIN(taxon1, taxon2) = MIN(:param1, :param2) AND MAX(taxon1, taxon2) = MAX(:param1, :param2)
```

There is also the option of [`ROW VALUES`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) with the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT taxon1, gene1, taxon2, gene2 
FROM orthologs 
WHERE (taxon1, taxon2) IN((25, 37), (37, 25))
```

or:

```
WHERE (25, 37) IN((taxon1, taxon2), (taxon2, taxon1))
```

You can use this for your 2nd requirement also:

```
SELECT taxon1, gene1, taxon2, gene2 
FROM orthologs 
WHERE (55, 123) IN((taxon1, gene1), (taxon2, gene2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, you could use `least()` and `greatest()` for this. But SQLite does not support those, so we can emulate them with conditional expressions:

```
where 
    case when taxon1 < taxon2 then taxon1 else taxon2 end = 25
    and case when taxon1 > taxon2 then taxon1 else taxon2 end = 37
```

Or beter yet, you can use `min()` and `max()`, as demonstrated in forpas' answer (+1).

That said, if you are looking for efficiency, you should implement a storage rule so that, for example, the smallest taxon is always stored in `taxon1`. This gives you the opportunity to simplify the whole thing as:

```
where taxon1 = 25 and taxon2 = 37
```

You can do this with a `check` constraint:

```
create table orthologs (
    taxon1 integer,
    ...
    check(taxon1 < taxon2)
);
```

Comment: SQLite has MIN() and MAX() functions.

Comment: Yes, I was considering that (smaller taxon always on the left). However, this still does not solve the gene problem (need to look up both columns). The other reason is that I prefer to keep the original order as produced by the authors of the flat file.